# question on Brownian Motion stopping time and end state

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

I came across this equation in my lecture notes, which states:
$P(T_a < t , W_t \ge a) = P(W_t \ge a)$  where $T_a = \min\{t \ge 0, W_t \ge a\}$.

I'm really confused by this equation: as far as I understand it, the R.H.S $P(W_t \ge a)$ is the probability that at the end of duration $t$, the Brownian Motion hits level $a$ and it doesn't really care about what happened within the $t$ time frame (meaning the Brownian Motion may or may not hit level a before the end of $t$). Whereas the L.H.S $P(T_a < t , W_t \ge a)$ clearly requires the the Brownian Motion hits a before the end of t. So shouldn't $P(T_a < t , W_t \ge a)$ be strictly less than $P(W_t \ge a)$? since R.H.S also includes such processes where $a$ is not hit a single time before the end of $t$.

Could someone please enlighten me on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Where you wrote $T_a=\min\{T\ge 0, W_t\ge a\}$, might you have meant $T_a=\min\{t\ge 0 : W_t\ge a\}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Yes Michael, that's what I meant, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: found this off the Internet http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/313/WienerProcess.pdf and on page 6, there's a proof to the equation in question, however, it seems wrong to me. In this paper, it argues:
$P(T_a < t) = 2P(W_t - W_(T_a) > 0 AND T_a < t)$ = 2$P(W_t > a)$ since $(W_t - W_(T_a) > 0 AND T_a < t)$ and $(W_t > a)$ represent the same event. But how does this make any sense? They are not the same event not the least because the latter doesn't require $T_a < t$. Am I missing something obvious here? Does $W_t > a$ require a being hit before t?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Brownian motion is (almost surely) continuous.  So if it is at or above level $a$ at time $t$, then by the intermediate value theorem, it (almost surely) *must* have hit level $a$ at some time at or prior to $t$.  (This assumes $W_0 = 0$ and $a > 0$.)  That gives you $P(T_a \le t, W_t \ge a) = P(W_t \ge a)$.  To replace $T_a \le t$ with $T_a < t$, note that if $T_a = t$ then $W_t = a$ which happens with probability 0.

Comment: Thanks Nate, that explains clearly. Appreciate your help!